# how to filter object from nested objects by specific unique key

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

This is input data, where i want filter a object by ID key

```
let myData = {
             "nodeInfo":
             {
                "9":
                {
                   "1": { "ID": "14835", "name": "Binod" },
                   "2": { "ID": "14836", "name": "Rahul" },
                   "3": { "ID": "14837", "name": "Sunil" },
                },
                "10":
                {
                   "4": { "ID": "14839", "name": "Shikhar" },
                   "5": { "ID": "14840", "name": "Hari" },
                   "6": { "ID": "14841", "name": "Harsh" },
                }
             }
          };
```

i want which object who have ID value 14835
so my result would be::  { "ID": "14835", "name": "Binod" }

Comment: there should be:: "10":
                {
                   "4": { "ID": "14839", "name": "Shikhar" },
                   "5": { "ID": "14840", "name": "Hari" },
                   "6": { "ID": "14841", "name": "Harsh" },
                }

Comment: ID key must have unique key, by mistake i kept duplicated values

Comment: If any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do it. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) That being said, welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Using an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), what about

```
getter = ID => Object.values(
    myData.nodeInfo
).map(
    o => Object.values(o).filter(
        v => v.ID === ID
    )[0]
)
```

and then

```
> getter("14835")
< (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

And, depending on whether your identifiers are unique or not, you can actually do

```
> getter("14835")[0]
< {ID: '14835', name: 'Binod'}
```

Comment: and what can be possible if object level is differ

Comment: [@Binod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18821656/binod-yadav) This would lead us to change `getter`'s body. Hard to be agnostic on that matter. One function per goal. Why ? `myData` is actually not representative of what you are dealing with ?

Answer (score 1):

This supports many levels of nested objects

```
function isObject(possibleObject) {
  return typeof possibleObject === 'object' && possibleObject !== null
}

function find(data, key) {
  for (const element of Object.values(data)) {
    if (element.ID) {
      if (element.ID === key) {
        return element;
      }

      continue;
    }

    if (isObject(element)) {
      const foundElement = find(element, key);
      if (foundElement !== null) {
        return foundElement;
      }
    }
  }

  // Not found
  return null;
}
``
```

Comment: Interesting but not 100% agnostic. E.g. against `{"ID": "X", "sub": {"ID": "Y"}}`.

Comment: Good point. A quick solution would be replacing ```if (element.ID) { if (element.ID === key) ... } continue;```with ```if (element.ID && element.ID === key) return element```, but there's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

@Gluey1017 has provided a very good answer that will return the first occurrence of an object with the given `ID` key. In the following snippet I modified/extended his script to also collect multiple results should they exist:

```js
const myData = {
         "nodeInfo":
         {
            "9":
            {
               "1": { "ID": "14835", "name": "Binod" },
               "2": { "ID": "14836", "name": "Rahul" },
               "3": { "ID": "14837", "name": "Sunil" },
            },
            "10":
            {
               "4": { "ID": "14839", "name": "Shikhar" },
               "5": { "ID": "14840", "name": "Hari" },
               "6": { "ID": "14841", "name": "Harsh" },
            },
            "15":
            { "7": {
                "8": { "ID": "14835" , "name": "Carsten" },
                "9": { "ID": "14842" , "name": "someone" }
            } }
         }
      };
function find(data,key){
 const found=[]; // results array
 function fnd(da) { // recursive function
  for (const el of Object.values(da)){
   if (el?.ID === key) found.push(el);
   if (typeof el==='object' && el !== null) fnd(el);
  }
 }
 fnd(data);
 return found;
}

console.log(find(myData,"14835"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spread operator to find item from a flat array of objects:

```
// get nodeInfo values
Object.values(myData.nodeInfo)
  // reduce to flat array of objects
  .reduce((acc,v) => [...acc, ...Object.values(v)],[])
  // assuming ID is unique find object
  .find(o => o.ID === "14835")
```

If the level is unknown, with data structured as above, recursion can be used to get to the level where objects have the desired properties.

Please notice that the function expects an array as its first parameter.

```js
// check for the presence of the relevant keys
const findByID = (vals, id) => vals.some(o => 'ID' in o && 'name' in o)
// if present find the value
? vals.find(o => o.ID === id)
// else repeat with level below
: findByID(vals.reduce((acc,v) => [...acc, ...Object.values(v)],[]), id);

findByID(Object.values(myData), "14835");
```

Comment: Upvoted for flattening via `reduce`. This is the path toward agnosticity according to me.